# Museo Sans readability for desktop

Tags: readability, legibility

Is there a way to measure readability for desktop? We are currently using **Museo Sans 14px** for body text and are wondering if increasing it to **16px** would help pages being read more easily? Is there any usability study for Museo Sans out there?

Comment: I think the best way is to simply look at it from a distance and validate if you can still read it farely well (and others as well). Perhaps this link can help you out more: http://usabilitygeek.com/12-typography-guidelines-for-good-website-usability/

Comment: I like the font but unfortunately never heard of a study about its legibility. There are a lot of general studies about legibility and you can always compare the Museo to the fonts that are researched. But if you want to do it quick and dirty, you can always copy-paste a blog post (you were about to read anyway) in the font you want to test and just see how it reads.

Answer (score 1):

There's no concrete usability study, but you can see some examples of Museo Sans at different font-size with 1.4em line-height along with body size comparison - https://typekit.com/fonts/museo-sans/n3/wfs

I would also recommend going through this article on Typekit - [Selecting typefaces for body text](http://practice.typekit.com/lesson/selecting-typefaces-for-body-text/) For Museo Sans, it says:

> Museo Sans' shapes are sturdy and its color is even, but its texture
>   is fairly dull. This is a clear example of a multipurpose font seeming
>   okay for body text, until it is compared with fonts made for that
>   purpose.

P.S - The following fonts are recommended for paragraphs by Typekit - https://typekit.com/fonts?recommended-for=paragraphs